# Recompile all packages and trigger on updates

Tags: apt, dpkg, compiling, build, install-from-source

I am using Ubuntu on a bespoke router and after seeing the latency drops capable with custom compiling on Gentoo, I would like to recompile all packages with CFLAGS="-march=atom". The [guide for this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/) and a [helpful forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=527454) demonstrate the recompilation steps:

```
export CFLAGS="-march=nocona"
export CXXFLAGS="-march=nocona"
apt-get build-dep packagename
apt-get -b source packagename
dpkg -i *.deb
```

Is it possible to automate a complete system recompilation instead of specifying one package at a time and to automatically recompile new package updates before they are installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look at [apt-build](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man1/apt-build.1.html) (not installed by default)

Comment: apt-build has "issues" with Natty, but at least it is an established project to contribute to. If you are after a polished, well packaged solution that you can leave unattended, this most likely is not the tool for you.

Comment: apt-build is no longer maintained. is there another way?