# Easy Native Package Rebuild

Tags: apt, customization, deb, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Recompile all packages and trigger on updates](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47906/recompile-all-packages-and-trigger-on-updates)

What's easiest way of to rebuild a package in Debian/Ubuntu using a specific set of `CFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS`. In all the tutorials I have read so far, for example [this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/rebuilding-ubuntu-debian-linux-binary-package/), they all refer to Debian's way which is about 5-10 command line calls depending what want to do.

But If I simply want to rebuild a package with `-march=native` it should be as *simple* as Gentoo's `CFLAGS=-march=native emerge PACKAGE`. Scripts for that any one?

Why isn't Ubuntu as user friendly as Gentoo in this aspect?

Answer (score 0):

Oops, I just discovered [this other](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47906/recompile-all-packages-and-trigger-on-updates) question! Seems to be exactly the thing I am looking for.